# Is there a way to follow redirects done by JS using PYTHON / SELENIUM?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, redirect

I'm trying to follow redirects done by sites and to get back the status codes (and URLs) for each redirect.
I'm using PYTHON 3. I've tried to do this in selenium and also using requests lib.

For some sites, requests work fine (I think it's because they use HTTP for the redirect?), but for other I can't see nothing (maybe they use JS? and I know there's some problems with that)

Here is an example:
https://www.onlinegamezone.club/searchresults.aspx?q=test&pid=ogz

If I go to this link, there is clearly a redirect to: https://www.bing.com/search?q=test
but I can't catch it in any way.

If it's indeed because of the use of JS, or for anything else - is there ANY way (in code) to follow these redirect links?
It doesn't have to be with selenium, I'm just trying to get the status code back.

I was thinking of wrapping my code with a proxy, to catch the network traffic, but I think it might be a bit too complicated...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Selenium follows redirects. Selenium just automates a browser. Unless you specifically created a session without JavaScript - the simple answer is the website is detecting and blocking you.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question a bit to make it more clear - I'm trying to get all the status codes (and urls) in between redirects until the final URL.
Selenium does follow these redirects, but there's no way for me to capture the URLs in between